# One variable in model becomes null after http post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, http-post

I'm having a problem with my model losing one of its values when submitted in a http post form.

The controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddTeam(int id)
{
    return PartialView("_AddTeam", ViewModelGenerator.TeamFormModel(id));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTeam(TeamFormModel model)
{
    TournamentTeamService.CreateTeam(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tournament", null);
}
```

The form model:

```
public class TeamFormModel
{
    public TeamViewModel Team { get; set; }
    public TournamentViewModel Tournament { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerViewModel> Players { get; set; }
}
```

This function is called from the controller, it creates a new instance of the form model and gets the Tournament from the database and puts it into a view model

```
public static TeamFormModel TeamFormModel(int id)
{
    var _db = new DbContext();
    var model = new TeamFormModel();
    var tempModel = new TournamentViewModel();

    var temp = (from t in _db.tournament
                        where t.Id == id
                        select t).SingleOrDefault();

    tempModel.Id = temp.Id;
    tempModel.Name = temp.Name;
    tempModel.SignupStartDate = temp.SignupStartDate;
    tempModel.SignupEndDate = temp.SignupEndDate;
    tempModel.StartDate = temp.StartDate;
    tempModel.EndDate = temp.EndDate;
    tempModel.Description = temp.description;
    tempModel.TournamentType = temp.TournamentType;

    model.Players = new List<PlayerViewModel>();
    model.Tournament = tempModel;

    return model;
}
```

Here's the view, the code with the inputs for the player list is missing, it's because it is appendedTo the player-forms div via jquery and it works perfectly so i didn't consider it relevant in this case.

```
@model Context.ViewModels.TeamFormModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddTeam", "Tournament", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <h2>Registering a team to @Model.Tournament.Name </h2>
    <div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Team.Name)
        <div class="control">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Team.Name)
        </div>
        <a  class="add-player-form" href="javascript:void(0)">Add a player</a>
        <div id="player-forms">

        </div>
    </div>    
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control" style="clear: both;">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Before i submit this form, the TeamFormModel is perfectly set up, all values are inserted and i only need to save everything to DB. However when it goes back to the controller, the tournament variable in TeamFormModel is null. So when i send it to a function that changes it to a Db model and submits it to db fails everytime.

I know there are ways around the problem like only keeping the id of the tournament instead of the whole model and then get it from db after the form is submitted but it really bugs me that it behaves this way.

I wasn't able to find anything on this specific issue here on stackoverflow, there were a few similar questions but nothing that presented it self the same way.

Comment: is the tournament id set?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't change after post.

Comment: where are controls to carry over the tournament object?

Comment: The tournament object is added to the model before being submitted to the view. I assumed the model binder wouldn't change that during post. Do i need to add something specific to the view so it doesn't disappear?

Comment: yes, every value you want carried from view to action method must have a control. No values are automatically carried. In this case, that means a control for every value within the tournament object. This is a major pain. I would just send the tournament id in a hidden control and pull the object when i reached the post action.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your help. I'll do it that way instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set something like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TournmentID);
```

something has to retain the value of the model that was passed into the view while the view is rendered, this will pass the value back to the controller on post

Comment: This was pointed out by Dave A in a previous comment. Marking this as the answer since i can't mark his. Thank you for your help.